# Block attached to spring oscillating on a surface with friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, harmonic-oscillator, spring

> [image]
>
> Consider a block of mass $m$ moving with initial velocity $v_o$ attached to a spring with spring constant $k$, on a terrain which has a coefficient of kinetic friction $\eta$ and coefficient of static friction $\epsilon$. Find the time taken for oscillations to die off.

If we write the force equation of block when it's moving to right, we get:

$$ ma = -kx - \eta mg$$

Or,

$$ a = -\frac{k}{m} x - \eta g$$

For a shifted harmonic oscillator of form:

$$ x(t) = A \cos(\omega t + \phi) + x_0 \tag{1}$$

$$ \ddot{x} = -\omega^2  ( x(t) - x_0) $$

Comparing with previous equation,

$$ - \eta g = - \omega^2 x_0$$

Hence,

$$ \frac{ \eta g}{\omega^2} = x_0 \tag{2}$$

By the fundamental equation of springs,

$$ \omega^2 = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} \tag{3}$$

Combining 1,2,3:

$$ x = A \cos( \frac{k}{m} t + \phi) + \frac{m \eta g}{k}$$

**Now the weird part:**

This would suggest that the oscillation would go on forever! However is well known that friction is a dissipative force and removes energy from the system, so if energy is being removed from the system in every cycle, why does the equation not show it?

#### Possible resolutions

Deeply thinking about the problem, I realized that my differential equation breaks whenever the velocity of the block drops to zero because then all of a sudden the static friction replaces the kinetic friction. I think so this sudden shift shouldn't cause too many problems but I'm not sure. How do you deal with the differential equation of motion suddenly shifting? Or is it some other problem which caused this strange result which I got?

**I'm mainly looking for an answer which discusses the break ups of the equation governing motion at when v drops to zero and sign of friction**

Update:  I found a paper discussing this, may write an answer later based on it [(see here)](https://projects.ncsu.edu/per/Articles/MarchewkaAbbott&Beichner.pdf)

Comment: Your final equation does not look like damped harmonic motion.  For much more info, see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda.html

Comment: Your problem is that the force equation is $ma=-k(x-x_0)-\eta mg$. So the term $\eta g$ is new and you have nothing to compare it with. It's an extra element that will change your dynamics.

Comment: Manipulating it a little bit makes it look the same, what's the problem with that?

Comment: Even if it's not damped oscillator, doesn't friction disspate energy @DavidWhite

Comment: @Buraian, yes, friction does dissipate energy.  That means that the amplitude follows an exponential function with a negative exponent, as indicated in the hyperphysics article.

Comment: Ok that's cool but here my friction is constant (except when the motion goes through a point of zero velocity), so I think we can use shifted oscillator instead the damped oscillator. Further more I don't think there is any equivalent term to friction in that equation

Comment: I think I got the problem but I'm not sure how to fix it.. it is that the friction keeps flipping sign depending on sign of velocity but I'm not sure how to account for that in diff eqn

Comment: @Buraian You're right. If I remember right, the best thing to do is to solve it in each regime separately, and then match the solutions.

Comment: There is no global solution? @Philip

Comment: Nono, that's not what I meant, I mean you write separate differential equations for each journey -- one for when the block is moving (say) leftward and one for when it's moving rightward -- and then you argue that the constants in these solutions should *match* when $v=0$, and that gets you the complete solution. This was a problem given by a prof I TA'd for a while ago, and I vaguely remember solving it like this. Not sure it's the only way.

Comment: Oh thank you, that makes sense. I'm mainly looking for an answer which discusses the break ups of the equation governing motion at when v drops to zero and sign of friction

Comment: [A similar question was asked recently](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/579040/mechanical-impedance-and-dynamic-stiffness-of-a-mass-spring-damper-system-incl) but has unfortunately received no answers.

Comment: The solution to this problem can be found on line, and it mentions: the analytic solution is hard. Moreover, there a different regions of validity depending on that starting position (e.g., it may not move at all). The key is to use energy considerations to show that the amplitude decrease is linear, not exponential, that is: it loses the same absolute (not relative) amplitude per oscillation.

Comment: Could you share a link of where you found a solution of this problem?

Comment: someone should type it up, it's a good problem: https://projects.ncsu.edu/per/Articles/MarchewkaAbbott&Beichner.pdf

Comment: Wow thank you, I don't think I'd have ever found that on my own

Answer (score 1):

> Or is it some other problem which caused this strange result which I got?

The problem is that your “friction” force, $\eta m g$, always points in the negative $x$ direction. It does not behave like friction which always points in the direction opposite $v$.

> I'm mainly looking for an answer which discusses the break ups of the equation governing motion at when v drops to zero and sign of friction

That is not the problem here. However, it is certainly possible to include such effects. Usually, a force law like that will not have an analytical solution and you will have to rely on numerical methods